# Почему useSelector берет данные не из того стора | ReduxToolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня есть 2 стора: Общий (там хранятся массивы) и Внутренний (там хранятся внутренние данные моего компонента).

Структура у них простая:

```
<Общий>
    {...}
    <Внутренний/>
</Общий>
```

Проблема в том, что когда я использую useSelector во внутреннем компоненте, то он выдает мне данные не из Общего стора, а из Внутреннего. Я понимаю, что это логично, но есть ли способ обойти это?

Answer (score 0):

Два стора - это перебор. Стор должен быть 1, разделённый на редьюсеры. Это общепризнанно, правильно с позиции архитектуры, и никто не запутается.

Но если уж очень надо! То обходной путь:
window.store1 = store; - во внешнем файле стора
window.store2 = store; - во внутреннем...

Теперь store1 и store2 - доступны из любого места. Хоть из консоли браузера.

Comment: Твой ответ правильный, но в window записывать нельзя. Лучше просто сделать export переменной и использовать в нужно месте.